# How to plot a comparisson of two fixed categorical values for linear regression of another continuous variable

Tags: r, plot, statistics, linear-regression

So I want to plot this:

> lmfit = lm (y ~ a + b)

but, "b" only has the values of zero and one. So, I want to plot two separate regression lines, that are paralel to one one another to show the difference that b makes to the y-intercept. So after plotting this:

> plot(b,y)

I want to then use `abline(lmfit,col="red",lwd=2)` twice, once with the x value of b set to zero, and once with it set to one. So once without the term included, and once where b is just 1b.

To restate: b is categorical, 0 or 1. a is continuous with a slight linear trend.

Thank you.

Example:

[image: comparison of different states of a categorical variable]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to consider using `predict(...)` with `b=0` and `b=1`, as follows. Since you didn't provide any data, I'm using the built-in `mtcars` dataset.

```
lmfit   <- lm(mpg~wt+cyl,mtcars)
plot(mpg~wt,mtcars,col=mtcars$cyl,pch=20)
curve(predict(lmfit,newdata=data.frame(wt=x,cyl=4)),col=4,add=T)
curve(predict(lmfit,newdata=data.frame(wt=x,cyl=6)),col=6,add=T)
curve(predict(lmfit,newdata=data.frame(wt=x,cyl=8)),col=8,add=T)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank's this is what I'm looking for. However I'm not familiar with the functions you are using. I'm relatively new to R. I'll look them up and decipher this, but if you have the time, please explain how this works.

Answer (score 1):

Given you have an additive lm model to begin with, drawing the lines is pretty straightforward, even though not completely intuitive. I tested it with the following simulated data:

```
y <- rnorm(30)
a <- rep(1:10,times=3)
b <- rep(c(1,0),each=15)

LM <- lm(y~a+b)
```

You have to access the coefficient values in the lm. Its is:

```
LM$coefficients
```

Here comes the tricky part, you have to assign the coefficients for each line.

The first one is easy:

```
abline(LM$coef[1],LM$coef[2])
```

The other one is a bit more complicated, given R works with additive coefficients, so for the second line you have:

```
abline(LM$coef[1]+LM$coef[3],LM$coef[2])
```

I hope this is what you was expecting

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've misunderstood the question, all you have to do is run `abline` again but on a model without the `b` term.

```
abline(lm(y~a),col="red",lwd=2)
```

Comment: no because without it the coefficient of "a" would be different. right? i need "b" in the equation but with it's x value set to 0.